# How does Angular-Cli know which environment to use?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I just started learning Angular2. I just wanted to understand how Angular-Cli knows which environment to run. I created multiple environments like prod, dev, beta and alpha and they seem to be called correctly when I `ng serve --environment={environment_name}`. Just wanted to be sure of my changes.

Answer (score 0):

`angular-cli` knows what environment to use, because you are passing the `--environment` flag.

If no flag is passed, then `dev` environment is used.

Comment: Oh. I meant when pushing to a server. How do I explicitly tell that this is currently running on live or currently running on qa?

Comment: Still not sure what you mean. Do you want to know in your app which environment is currently running? Import `environment.ts` from your enviroments folder, it is overwritten with the current environment at build-time.

Comment: I think what I'm trying to figure out is how it would go and use my other environment when it's actually running since I have 4 different apiurls for different environments and there seems to be no place to tell it to run this environment if you're in this `window.location.hostname` like how RestAngular has it.

Comment: I have literally no idea what you're trying to do, sorry.

Answer (score -1):

We configure which environment to use in **Angular-cli.json**

Checkout the image
[image]

Comment: That config file is **text**. Why on earth would you express it in the form of a screenshot instead of as text?!

Comment: This is utterly wrong anyway. The question is asking how Angular determines which environment is used. Your screenshot just shows how three different envionments are defined.